# Asp.NET - Identity 2 ResetPasswordAsync Invalid Token Error for Complex Passwords

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a reset password method based on Identity 2 as below

```
private async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ChangePasswordDto model)
{
    var userEntity = _userManagerRepository.FindById(model.UserId);
    if (userEntity == null)
        return ActionResult.Error(MessageResult.Error(MessageKey.InvalidCredential));

    //Only happe for complex passwords such as ">\{}[]+aB123"
    var changePasswordResult = await _userManagerRepository.ResetPasswordAsync(userEntity.Id, model.Token, model.Password);

    return !changePasswordResult.Succeeded
        ? changePasswordResult.ToActionResult(new Guid(userEntity.Id), userEntity.UserName)
        : ActionResult.Success(MessageResult.Succeed(MessageKey.PasswordChanged));
}
```

it works perfect if I pass a simple password to reset such as 
"**Abc@123**",

but returning Invalid Token error for more complex passwords including brackets and plus signs such as 
"**>{}[]+aB123**"

Anybody had this issue before or know any workaround?

Please note

- Above complex password is working in Signup
- All other details are perfect such as Token and User parameters to ResetPasswordAsync method

Appreciate any help